Ошибка при подклюении кода Си к Go проекту
Не могу сбилдить простейший проект на golang с подключением Си
main.go:
package main

/*
#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++
#include "mylib.h"
*/

import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 5
    b := 10
    result := C.add(C.int(a), C.int(b))
    fmt.Printf("Result of add(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, int(result))
}

mylib.cpp:
#include "mylib.h"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

mylib.h:
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

extern "C" {
    int add(int a, int b);
}

#endif

Ошибка:
go build -x -o myprogram main.go
WORK=/tmp/go-build82245532
mkdir -p $WORK/b001/
cd /home/anon/GolandProjects/CGO
TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='' /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/b001/ -importpath command-line-arguments "-ldflags=\"-O2\" \"-g\"" -- -I $WORK/b001/ -O2 -g ./main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:15:12: could not determine kind of name for C.add

ОС Linux
CGO_ENABLED=1
gcc -c mylib.cpp -o mylib.o - компилирует без ошибок

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка

extern "C" { уберите или сделайте макросом, это может быть нужно при включении его в С++. Пустую строку перед import "C"  уберите, иначе комментарий не будет разобран.

Большое спасибо! Уже очтаялся найти решение. Все получилось!


Убрать пустую строку между CGO preamble и обьявлением import "C":
/*
#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++
#include "mylib.h"
*/

import "C"


сделать макросом extern "C" в файле заголовка mylib.h:
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int add(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif


Скомпилировать С++ файл в обьектный:
g++ -c -std=c++11 mylib.cpp -o mylib.o


добавить mylib.o к параметрам линковки в файле main.go:
/*
#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++ mylib.o
#include "mylib.h"
*/



Спасибо
user7860670 за ответ.
